# $http in angular returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, express, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass via angular $http a post request 2 paramters

code this inside some controller.js (which pass right data)

```
$http
  .post('/users', {
    user_name: sessionInfo.get().name,
    room_name: sessionInfo.get().room
  })
  .success(function(data) {

  })
  .error(function(data) {

  });
```

code that is inside server. js

```
//get the body of req
app.post('/users', function(req, res){
    console.log("the body of the post request is---->"+req.body);
});
```

however the console log prints undefined.

why? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used `body-parser` ?

Comment: Which console log prints undefined? You have two.

Comment: Rayon - no
@JLRishe - The 2nd one, from server.js

Comment: you need `npm install --save body-parser` and then hook it up in your app with `app.use`

Comment: Thanks. is body-parser mandatory? can't I just pass the body of the post request as I did in my msg's code?

Comment: body parser is mandatory if you want human readable post data